# ActionSupport not calling my function in controller

Tags: rerender, actionsupport, form

What I'm trying to do is rerender my form once a row in the table is clicked. Initially, I have just put a system debug line in the function in the controller and I have not been able to see it in the debug log since the action support is not going there. Not sure why honestly...

VF Page :

```
<apex:column width="50px;">
  <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
     <apex:outputpanel>
         <apex:actionSupport event="onRowClick" action="{!setSource}" reRender="form">
           <apex:param name="temp.name" value="{!temp.Name}"/>
           <apex:param name="temp.id" value="{!temp.ID}"/>
          </apex:actionSupport>
     {!temp.Name}
     </apex:outputpanel>
</apex:column>
```

Btw, this column is part of an apex page block table :

```
<apex:pageBlockTable rows="5" rendered="{!selectedObject=='ACCOUNT' && foundResults==true}"
value="{!searchResultsAcc}" var="temp">
```

Function in controller :

```
public void setSource() {
   System.debug('Inside setSource()');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

onRowClick is only when you're using [apex:dataTable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataTable.htm) or [apex:pageBlockTable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm). You can't use it with [apex:actionSupport](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm). You'll probably want to just use "onclick" as the event.

---

Working demo of passing a value back to the row-click:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="Accounts">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="accountRecord" onrowclick="alert(this.firstChild.dataset.id)">
            <apex:column html-data-id="{!accountRecord.Id}" value="{!accountRecord.Name}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

You can call an actionFunction (not shown here) to pass parameters to the controller.

---

Demo calling actionFunction:

Controller:

```
public class highlightRowController {
    public Id selectedId { get; set; }
    public Integer selectCount { get; set; }
    public highlightRowController() {
        selectCount = 0;
    }
    public Account[] getAccounts() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 100];
    }
    public void incrementCounter() {
        selectCount++;
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="highlightRowController">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:actionFunction name="highlightRow" reRender="form" action="{!incrementCounter}">
            <apex:param name="selectedId" assignTo="{!selectedId}" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Times function called: {!selectCount}">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="account" onrowclick="highlightRow(this.firstChild.dataset.id)">
                <apex:column value="{!account.Name}{!if(selectedId=account.Id,' (Selected)','')}" html-data-id="{!account.Id}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```